# Jekyll, show first 5 popular tags in collection's posts

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I already have a working code that displays all the tags in the collection posts and counts their number in all posts.

Here:

```
{% assign tags =  site.blog | map: 'tags' | uniq %}
{% assign postInTagCount = 0 %}
<div class="blog-tags__tags-wrapper">
{% for tag in tags %}
    <a href="/blog/tags/#{'#'}{{ tag | downcase }}">
        <div class="tags_wrapper__tag">
            {{ tag }}
            {% for post in site.blog %}
                {% if post.tags contains tag %}
                    {% capture postInTagCount %}{{ postInTagCount | plus:1 }}{% endcapture %}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if postInTagCount <> 0 %} [{{ postInTagCount }}]{% endif %}
            {% capture postInTagCount %}0{% endcapture %}
        </div>
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

But I would like to display the 5 most popular tags that are found in the posts of the selected collection.

I have an example: https://www.codeofclimber.ru/tags/
But I'm not sure if Jekyll is used on this site or not. On Gitkhab in the author's repositories, I did not find his site.

I ask for your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the site does use Jekyll. :)

Check out his [article](https://www.codeofclimber.ru/2015/sorting-site-tags-in-jekyll/) to see how he did it using a custom liquid filter or contact him directly on SO @hal.

Comment: He uses a plugin written in Ruby. I do not know Ruby at all ... I'd like to do without him if I can.

Comment: @VostokSisters I don't believe it's possible to do what you want without a plugin.

Comment: Maybe I will ... and yet I was able to find the most popular among all the tag. [Screenshot](http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2017/10/29/0001/0403/94611/11/a6a166b72a.png)

Comment: Nah... I'd rather form json from objects { tag: {{ tagName }}, count: {{ tagCount }} } and then sorting in JS and show in html. It will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe by capturing the loops and writing in it:
First the var PostInTagCount, a separator of your choice which can't appear in tag name, then the tag, then a secondary separator.

When it's done you split your capture by the secondary separator and create a new loop sorting by A..B. as first character is your var PostInTagCount it should do the job.